# Javascript Geocoding API (Google) Region filter

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geocoding, region

today i had a problem using the Geocoding-API:
When i searched for a Administrative area in germany (Sachsen) i only found Sachsen in Baden-Württemberg, which is a small city. After some testing i found that the problem was the "region"-Parameter, if i left that out the geocoding api also found the administrative area Sachsen. Here is an example request:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sachsen&sensor=false&language=de&region=de

Here without region:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sachsen&sensor=false&language=de

Both results are located in Germany (de). So it seems like a bug, that the geocoding-api does not find any adminsitrative areas if a region is used in the request.

Can anyone confirm that problem?

Many greetings,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like the region biased result doesn't include the administrative area.

If you need just the administrative area maybe you can use `components` with `country` and `administrative_area`:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sachsen&sensor=false&language=de&region=de&components=country:DE|administrative_area:DE](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sachsen&sensor=false&language=de&region=de&components=country:DE%7Cadministrative_area:DE)